# Geonames database encoding for cyrillic symbols

Tags: encoding, geonames

I have problem with geonames.org database imported into MySQl. I use utf8_general_ci on table 'alternatenames', but have incorrect encoding on cyrillic names (for example, objects like Ð¢ÑƒÑ€). Is there some good practice to make characters appear correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I used utf8mb4 encoding (new standard of geonames encoding) instead of simple utf8. All cyrillic characters are correct now.